# javascript new popup page in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm  new in web programming and I have some problem.
I want to open a new popup php page from a link clicked but is not work..

> from this link

```
echo '<td><a href="#" onClick = "open("../common/sqlDetail_Inform_Reservation.php?id='.$row['Reservation_ID'].'");">OPEN</a></td>';
```

> Script function

```
function open(url) {
      var popup = window.open(url, "_blank", "width=200, height=200") ;
      popup.location = url;
    }
```

Best regard : D

Comment: Quotes, quotes, quotes

Comment: To add what John Conde correctly pointed out :) Press `F12` on your browser, see Console and view it's errors in the future. For ***any*** browser issues, consult to the Console Screen first.

Comment: Aside from that, if your end goal is simply to get an anchor tag to open in a new window and don't care if it's done via javascript or not, would be to add target="window" to your html.

Comment: Popups are a horribly annoying thing. Even if you open them just when the user clicks a button. Consider using inline dialogs.

Comment: Agree with @ThiefMaster

Answer (score 2):

You have a quotes issue. You need to escape your double quotes that inside a double quoted string:

```
echo '<td><a href="#" onClick = "open(\"../common/sqlDetail_Inform_Reservation.php?id='.$row['Reservation_ID'].'\");">OPEN</a></td>';
```

Comment: And he should do a `return false;` at last line of his javascript function open too.

Comment: thank you for you guys but it's still not work , no any response on my link  TT

Answer (score 1):

You have conflict with quotes, try with that:

```
echo '<td><a href="#" onClick = "open(\'../common/sqlDetail_Inform_Reservation.php?id='.$row['Reservation_ID'].'\');">OPEN</a></td>';
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a elegant solution to avoid to many click handlers,it uses the new attribute data-SOMETHING to store your id.if you want more compatibility you can also use the rel attribute or title or whatever to store the id.
less code,faster javascript,easy to edit later.

```
<table>
<?php
while($row blabla ){
 echo "<tr>
  <td>".$row['bla1']."</td>
  <td data-id=\"".$row['Reservation_ID']."\">open</td>
 </tr>";
}
?>
</table>
<script>
function open(e){
 if(e.target.dataset['id']){
  window.open('blabla/Reservation.php?id='+e.target.dataset['id']);
 }
}
document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0].addEventListener('click',open,false)
</script>
```

if you don't understand something just ask

example in javascript...

http://jsfiddle.net/V5Kn5/